# React: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

I have cloned this project https://github.com/LaurenceHo/react-weather-app#webpack-reactjs-and-typescript.

I have followed all the steps correctly, i have created my new Key here https://api.windy.com/keys in Map Forecast API and put as instruction here https://github.com/LaurenceHo/react-weather-app/blob/master/src/views/weather-map.tsx.

Now I run the server and I get this error for this method `getWeather`.

I look up in my Network and Console, these are the errors I can see, but I do not get how I can fix it:

[image]

[image]

This is the API with the method:

```
export const getWeatherByTime = (
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number,
  time: number,
  exclude: string,
  units: string
): Promise<Forecast> => {
  const requestUrl =
    `${CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL}getWeather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&time=${time}` +
    `&exclude=${encodeURIComponent(exclude)}&units=${encodeURIComponent(units)}`;
  return fetch(requestUrl)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then((data: any) => data);
};
```

How can I figure the problem out? How can I solve it?

Comment: Is your development server running? It's making a call to `localhost:3000`...

Comment: yes it is running on http://localhost:8080/, but the request is done to http://localhost:3000..can this be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GitHub project you cloned said this in the `README.md` file:

> Because we don't want to use Google Cloud Function when we do local development, we write simple NodeJs Express server for returning JSON response. Move to dev-server folder `cd dev-server`, and run `npm i` to install the npm modules. After that, run `npm start` to start NodeJs Express Server and we can move forward to frontend development.

Move to the `dev-server` folder and do `npm start` after installing your npm packages - it seems that would start a development server on port 3000.